# Creating nested association records Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, nested-attributes

Apparently I am overlooking something very simple in the example I have done below where I am attempting to create nested association records while instantiating a new parent record.

I'm hoping a fresh set of eyes my help find what has been eating at me for days. Thanks in advance!
What am I missing/messing up? It seems so trivial.

ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes is obviously unhappy.

```
class ContentGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_protected

  has_many :contents, :dependent=>:destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contents
end
```

---

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base 
  attr_protected

  has_one :sort_item, :as=>:sortable
  belongs_to :content_group, :dependent=>:destroy

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :sort_item
end
```

---

```
class SortItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :position, :sortable_id, :sortable_type
  belongs_to :sortable, :polymorphic=>true
end
```

---

## in rails console, lightly nested call works as expected:

```
> p = {"sort_item_attributes"=>{"position"=>"1"}}
> b = Content.new(p)
 => Content id: nil, content_group_id: nil
```

## one additional nest blows up:

```
> p = {"contents_attributes"=>{"sort_item_attributes"=>{"position"=>"1"}}}
> cg = ContentGroup.new(p)

 ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: position
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:88:in `block in assign_attributes'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `each'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `assign_attributes'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/base.rb:498:in `initialize'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:183:in `new'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:183:in `build_association'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:233:in `build_record'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:112:in `build'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:406:in `block in assign_nested_attributes_for_collection_association'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:401:in `each'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:401:in `assign_nested_attributes_for_collection_association'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:289:in `contents_attributes='
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:94:in `block in assign_attributes'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:93:in `each'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:93:in `assign_attributes'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/base.rb:498:in `initialize'
    from (irb):10:in `new'
    from (irb):10
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
```

Hope this can be fixed, sorry if there's an obvious mistake on my part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well this ended up being really stupid and the error log didn't help at all, not even a little. So, I ended up messing around with the hash that you are supposed to be able to pass to Model.new() in order to instantiate all associations that are nested within the hash (rails doc is very good a majority of the time). But, what I found out that seems to be undocumented (unless someone can point me in the right direction of it's location in the doc's) is that:

> you must assign a key to a ARRAY of hashes in order to correctly
>   instantiate a new child association record:

*(example  rails console)*

**INCORRECT:**

```
> p = {"contents_attributes"=>{"sort_item_attributes"=>{"position"=>"1"}}}
```

**CORRECT:**

```
> p = {"contents_attributes"=>[{"sort_item_attributes"=>{"position"=>"1"}}]}
```

Notice the very subtle difference: you NEED to have the key for the nested association, - **"contents_attributes"**, point to an ARRAY -  **[{"sort_item_attributes"=>{"position"=>"1"}}]**, because it is a content_groups, in this case, has_many contents.

A has_one relationship, such as that of content has_one sort_item, lacks this necessity.

In theory, this makes complete sense, but the error log didn't point me in any good directions to solve the issue I was having, and the rails doc's seemed to fall short. I ended up having to read some of the nested_attributes.rb code/examples lines 93-95. Also it didn't help that I was doing a bunch of ajax work that lend me to this problem, so my brain was a little out of sorts.

Hopefully the time I spent banging my head on this one will help someone find a quick answer to a same/similar problem.